# Connecting to Wireless Network

Tags: wireless, networking

How do i connect to a wireless network without a internet connection. 
 **I don't have any  windows OS running along side my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.**

Pci Card : 54mbps wireless NETGEAR WG311v3 .

Answer (score 0):

I use ndiswrapper to connect to wireless on ubuntu 12.04
which you can find a tutorial here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper